# Equivalence of the two boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

This is a question from a textbook on digital logic which I am having a difficult time with:
Prove that the following expression is valid:
$\bar{x_1}x_3+x_1x_2\bar{x_3}+\bar{x_1}x_2+x_1\bar{x_2}=\bar{x_2}x_3+x_1\bar{x_3}+x_2\bar{x_3}+\bar{x_1}x_2x_3$

My attempt at the proof:
Using Demorgan's Theorem I am able to simplify the LHS to
$x_1(\bar{x_2}+\bar{x_3})+\bar{x_1}(x_3+x_2)$ (Since $x+\bar{x}y=x+y$),
and applying the same procedure to the RHS I have
$x_3(\bar{x_2}+\bar{x_1})+\bar{x_3}(x_1+x_2)$,
which the two sides are clearly not identical to each other. So is there any other means of simplifying the expression further?

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try breaking these down.  So $\bar{x_1}x_3+\cdots = \bar{x_1}x_2x_3+\bar{x_1}\bar{x_2}x_3 + \cdots$ and so on. Then remove duplicates.

As far as I can tell, you will be left with the same six terms on each side.

Comment: Indeed so!! Thank you for your help! I think with my approach I would have to use the same technique.